# AWS S3 Video Upload React Native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, video, expo, html5-video

**I am using AWS S3 to upload videos from an Expo App. Most of the examples I see have been with mp4 files. When I get the uri from Expo ImagePicker I receive a mov file. I'm curious to know how to properly upload video files from a React Native app to AWS S3**

This is my code for uploading a video to S3:

```
const uploadVideoToS3 = async (file: any) => {
    const date = new Date().toISOString();

    const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 7);
    const cleanFileName = file.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, "-");
    const newFileName = `${randomString}-${date}-${cleanFileName}`;

    const newFile = new ReactNativeFile({
      uri: file,
      name: newFileName,
      type: `${file.split(".").pop()}`,
    });

    AWS.config.update({
      region: "eu-north-1",
      credentials: new AWS.Credentials(AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY),
    });

    let upload_params = {
      Bucket: "bucket-name",
      Key: file,
      Body: file,
      Acl: "public-read",
    };

    let upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({ params: upload_params });

    let promise = upload.promise();
    promise.then(
      function (data) {
        // ! Log only for testing
        console.log("Successfully uploaded:", data);
        // console.log(data);
        // setVideoSource(data.Location);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log("Failed to upload", newFile, "with error:", err.message);
      }
    );
  };
```

I've also trying to use CloudFront to serve the videos, but since I have not come further than trying to upload videos to S3 an answer here would be great!

Comment: Not clear what is the problem... So you use the ImagePicker, and does it then successfully upload your selected MOV to the Amazon S3 folder? All S3 does is store files so it shouldn't give problems about the format of the user uploaded file. PS: If you want to play video online via browsers then use MP4 format since it is most supported. If you only have MOV then you need to convert it somehow.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The problem isn't to upload the file to S3, I can do that. The problem is that the url from S3 doesn't work for a Video component in React Native. I have never worked with videos and so I had no idea what the problem was. How could I convert MOV files to mp4?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have also tried the aws-sdk but still not able to upload I have tried the presigned url in backend then uploading the video works for me.

```js
const uploadVideo = (token, data) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({type: ASSET_LOADING});
    const fileName = data.assets[0].fileName;
    const fileType = 'mp4';
    const fileSize = data.assets[0].fileSize / 1024;
    const duration = data.assets[0].duration;
    const fileUrl = data.assets[0].uri;
    let success;
    let url;

    await api
      .post(
        'upload/presigned-url',
        {
          fileName,
          fileType,
          fileSize,
          duration,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            token,
          },
        },
      )
      .then(response => {
        success = true;
        url = response.data.data.directUploadURL;
        dispatch({
          type: UPLOAD_VIDEO,
          payload: response.data.data.videoId,
          image: response.data.data.thumbnailUrl,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({type: UPLOADING_FAILED});
      });

    if (success) {
      const formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append('file', {
        uri: fileUrl,
        name: fileName,
        type: `application/${fileType}`,
      });
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formdata,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      };

      fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          dispatch({type: UPLOADING_SUCCESS, payload: 'Uploading Success'});
        })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch({type: UPLOADING_FAILED, payload: 'Uploading failed'});
        });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```